# Определить символ, который чаще всего встречается в файле после двух одинаковых символов

Tags: python, циклы

**Задача:**

Текстовый файл содержит только заглавные буквы латинского алфавита (ABC…Z). Определите символ, который чаще всего встречается в файле после двух одинаковых символов. Например, в тексте 'CCCBBABAABCC' есть комбинации CCC, CCB, BBA и AAB. Чаще всего — 2 раза — после двух одинаковых символов стоит B, в ответе для этого случая надо написать 'B'.

Мой код (ответ выдаёт неверный):

```
file = open('88.txt')
all = list(file.readline())
litteral = []
count, max, wMax = 0, 0, ''

for i in range(0, len(all)-2):
    if all[i] == all[i+1]:
        litteral.append(all[i+2])
for k in range(0, len(litteral)-1):
    if litteral[k] == litteral[k+1]: count+=1
    else: count = 0
    if count > max: 
        max = count
        wMax = litteral[k]

print(wMax, litteral)
```

Файл с данными: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/mUCkZfFCA13ccg
Верный ответ для данных из файла: 'K'

Прошу помочь разобрать задачу или как-то исправить мой код...

Comment: ++ за отлично оформленный вопрос! Понятная формулировка задачи в виде текста (не фото), присутствует собственная попытка решения, пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат. Было бы здорово если бы все новые участники SO так же оформляли свои вопросы)

Comment: @MaxU вопрос только оформлен хорошо, но сам, "вот моя задачка, я как-то решил, исправьте мне" - плох и бесполезен. Даже входные данные не включены в тело вопроса, в по ссылке которая протухнет через неделю.

Comment: @Kromster, согласен, заголовок можно было бы улучшить. Но по сравнению с другими "учебными" вопросами - этот оформлен почти безупречно) ЗЫ переименовал заголовок

Comment: @MaxU на всякий случай, напомню, что SO это не сбор условий задачек и не онлайн база решателей задачек за студентов, а сбор базы знаний. То есть хороший вопрос должен был бы иметь вид "Как найти символ, который чаще всего встречается в файле после двух одинаковых символов", и в таком виде - закрыт после непродолжительно отладки.

Comment: @Kromster, повторюсь - все познается в сравнении. По сравнению с другими "учебными" вопросами этот оформлен отлично, особенно если учесть, что автор новичек (это его первый вопрос)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я, кажется, понял, как вы хотели подсчитать максимальное количество символов, и если мое понимание правильное, то вы забыли написать `litteral.sort()` перед вторым циклом. Кроме этого есть еще небольшая ошибка, из-за которой count для каждой буквы на один меньше, чем должен быть. С исправлением ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
file = open('88.txt')
string = list(file.readline()) #all - это стандартная функция в питоне, поэтому не стоит к ней что-то присваивать
litteral = []
count, max_count, max_letter = 1, 0, '' #max - тоже функция, поэтому его тоже не стоит использовать

for i in range(0, len(string) - 2):
    if string[i] == string[i+1]:
        litteral.append(string[i+2])

litteral.sort()
        
for k in range(len(litteral)-1):
    if litteral[k] == litteral[k+1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 1
    if count > max_count: 
        max_count = count
        max_letter = litteral[k+1]

print(max_letter) #K
```

Я добавил сортировку, исправил пару багов и внес пару правок, но это ваш код.

Вообще, можно быстрее, да и кода поменьше:

```
file = ...
string = ...
count = [0] * 26 #можно заменить на словарь

for i in range(len(string) - 2):
    if string[i] == string[i + 1]:
        count[ord(string[i + 2]) - ord('A')] += 1

res = max((count[i], i) for i in range(26))
res_letter = chr(res[1] + ord('A'))
print(res_letter) #K
```

Со словарем:

```
...
count = {chr(i): 0 for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)} 

for i in range(len(string) - 2):
    if string[i] == string[i + 1]:
        count[string[i + 2]] += 1

res = max(count, key=count.get)
print(res)
```

C Counter'ом:

```
from collections import Counter

...
count = Counter() 

for i in range(len(string) - 2):
    if string[i] == string[i + 1]:
        count[string[i + 2]] += 1

print(count.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам за разбор и пояснения.

Comment: `collections.Counter` предназначен для подсчётов вхождений.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy зачем что-то импортировать, когда можно обойтись встроенными методами без особых нагромождений? Я большой приверженец оптимизаций, и даже писать через словари кажется мне кощунством)). Если надо, могу добавить и с Counter'ом вариант.

Comment: Ваш вариант ограничивает алфавит. С Counter этого ограничения не будет. Но вы правы, это уже дело вкуса.

Comment: Со словарём, кстати, красивый вариант

Answer (score 6):

Ладно, добавлю и я свой вариант:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('88.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

counter = Counter(c for a,b,c in zip(text,text[1:],text[2:]) if a == b)
print(counter.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Вывод:

```
K
```

Comment: элегантное решение с `zip(text,text[1:],text[2:])` :)

Comment: @MaxU Ну, на самом деле вот как-раз этот фрагмент не выглядит элегантным, но строка вычисления в целом по-моему выглядит бешено понятной, а я люблю, когда всё понятно )

Comment: я тоже за понятный  и легко-читаемый код)

Comment: @MaxU Чтобы не повторяться можно написать `zip(*(text[i:] for i in range(3)))`, но что-то это не выглядит проще, ладно %)

Comment: нет, это будет явным ухудшением - в оригинальном варианте намерения автора очень понятно, а здесь - нет :)

Answer (score 4):

Функция `enum_chars` перебирает все символы, которые следуют за парой одинаковых. `zip` перемещает по тексту три итератора в интервалом в единицу.

Функция `most_popular` считает все такие символы и выбирает самый популярный:

```
import collections


def enum_chars(text):
    it1 = iter(text)
    it2 = iter(text)
    next(it2, None)
    it3 = iter(text)
    next(it3, None)
    next(it3, None)
    return (c for a, b, c in zip(it1, it2, it3) if a == b)


def most_popular(text):
    c = collections.Counter(enum_chars(text))
    mc = c.most_common(1)
    if mc:
        return mc[0][0]
    return ''


print(most_popular('abc'))
print(most_popular('CCCBBABAABCC'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
text = 'CCCBBABAABCC'

res_dict = dict()
for i in range(2, len(text)):
    if text[i-1] == text[i-2]:
        res_dict[text[i]] = res_dict.get(text[i], 0) + 1 

result = max(res_dict, key=res_dict.get)
```

```
>>> result
'B'
```

Comment: Функция `count` сосчитает и вхождения символа, которые не следуют за двумя одинаковыми символами. Это правильно?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в `result_list` только те буквы, что идут после двух одинаковых, но да, можно и без `count`

Comment: Почему вы не рассматриваете в цикле последний символ text[-1]? И что вообще делает последняя строка? Если я не разучился читать, то она находит максимальный символ, который встречается после "дублей" хотя бы два раза. Как мне кажется, это не совсем то, о чем просил автор вопроса, и я не понимаю, почему ваш ответ отмечен верным. На строке 'CCCBBABAAAABCC' он уже дает неверный ответ. Вдобавок, этот код работает за квадрат, так что на строке длины миллион, данной нам автором вопроса, он будет работать немного долговато.

Comment: Да, что-то алгоритм немного того. Надо тщательнее переделать. Как минимум 3 ошибки в нём. Ой нет - 4 ошибки, ещё и `result_list` не инициализирован.

Comment: @EzikBro `len(text)` исправил, спасибо! последняя строка считает, какой символ встречается чаще

Comment: @Jack_oS Перечитайте ещё раз что написал EzikBro, он абсолютно прав, последняя строка считает какую-то ересь. Там `if` не нужен, но нужен `key=` в котором и нужно брать `count`

Comment: @Jack_oS в этой строке A встречается трижды после дублей, а B - только дважды.

Comment: @EzikBro я про "CCCBBABAABCC"... не выспался сегодня, наверное